# Conformal transformation in Java - disc to rectangle

Tags: java, image, mapping, transformation

I have to conformally map an image, from a disc to a rectangle.

[Image - disc to rectangle transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riuig.png)
[image: disc to rectangle transformation]

The circle in the attached image can be considered as a disc with an inner radius of zero. The red line in the image marks the start, and the blue line marks the end.

I've tried using [AffineTransform](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) in Java, but it doesn't allow you to define custom transformations. Can someone help me tackle this problem?

Comment: I gave +1 because some idiot made it -1

Answer (score 2):

You only need to transform from polar to cartesian coordinates.

Example code is provided on [mindprod page](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/polar.html).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `AffineTransform` because your transformation is not an affine one: it does not preserve straightness and parallelness of lines. You can, however, define your own `Transformation` interface and provide whatever implementations you like, with `transform` methods similar to those in the `AffineTransform` class. You will have to think about what to do when dealing with the point at the exact centre of the disc.

Answer (score 1):

In the case when you do not need to write the code and are only interested in the result, use imageMagick

source :
https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#depolar